# All system text is covered by white boxes

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, firefox, fonts, visual-artifacts

Pretty much the title. I was normally using Ubuntu the other day and I tried to launch Firefox. It gave me a crash report which I closed, and then it refused to launch. I then restarted my computer and then I was greeted to all of my system text to my covered with white boxes or being empty boxes. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

---

What can I do to fix this problem?

**NOTE**: The text within applications like chrome still seem to be fine, just in case that's relevant. Also, my specs are an i7 8086k, and a GTX 1060 6GB if it's a graphics driver issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does changing the fonts make a difference?

Comment: I can't change the system font unfortunately so I have no clue. Tweaks has the same issue as the rest of the system fonts, so it's all an incoherent mess. I did get to the font switching option, but it didn't let me switch. I am using the default Ubuntu character set so I don't see why it would be an issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Did it go away?

Comment: @Zanna nope, I ended up uninstalling the dual boot anyways so it's whatever. Sorry this thread couldn't be of more use for anyone who was having the same issue